# Remove element from json array by condition sql server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following json data

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @JSONData = N'{  
        "FirstName":"Jignesh",  
        "LastName":"Trivedi",  
        "Code":"CCEEDD",  
        "Addresses":[  
            { "Address":"Test 0", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
            { "Address":"Test 1", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"}  
        ]  
    }'
```

I need to remove element from an array with a condition (using json_modify of other sql server 2016 functions), for example I want to  delete address which value is "Test 1". Can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [JSON_MODIFY (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)

Comment: I used json modify, but it allows to delete only with index (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: somethig like this - SELECT @JSONData = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData, '$.Addresses[0]', null)

Comment: Even when you do have the index, this is way more difficult than it should be, because you can't remove elements by index. There's an [open feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32895733-add-a-delete-option-for-json-modify-to-remove) for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution:**

`JSON_MODIFY()` doesn't support `delete` option in `path` argument, so one possible approach here is to empty `"Addresses"` JSON array and then fill this array with matching items. For SQL Server 2016+ you may try to generate and execute a dynamic statement. If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may pass a variable as `path` argument.

**Example for SQL Server 2016+:**

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @JSONData = N'{  
   "FirstName":"Jignesh",  
   "LastName":"Trivedi",  
   "Code":"CCEEDD",  
   "Addresses":[  
       { "Address":"Test 0", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 1", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 2", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 3", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 4", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"}  
   ]  
}'

DECLARE @JSONOutput AS NVARCHAR(4000)    
SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData, '$.Addresses', JSON_QUERY('[]'))

DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @stm = @stm + CONCAT(
   'SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONOutput, ''append $.Addresses'', JSON_QUERY(@JSONData, ''$.Addresses[',
   [key],
   ']'')); '
)
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.Addresses')
WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.Address') <> N'Test 1'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stm, N'@JSONOutput AS NVARCHAR(4000) OUTPUT, @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000)', @JSONOutput OUTPUT, @JSONData
PRINT @JSONOutput
```

**Example for SQL Server 2017+:**

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @JSONData = N'{  
   "FirstName":"Jignesh",  
   "LastName":"Trivedi",  
   "Code":"CCEEDD",  
   "Addresses":[  
       { "Address":"Test 0", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 1", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 2", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 3", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
       { "Address":"Test 4", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"}  
   ]  
}'

DECLARE @JSONOutput AS NVARCHAR(4000)    
SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData, '$.Addresses', JSON_QUERY('[]'))
SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONOutput, 'append $.Addresses', JSON_QUERY(@JSONData, '$.Addresses[' + [key] + ']'))
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.Addresses')
WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.Address') <> N'Test 1'
```

**Update:**

If `"Addresses"` item has a fixed structure, another possible option is to use `OPENJSON()` and `FOR JSON PATH`:

```
SELECT @JSONData = JSON_MODIFY(
   @JSONData,
   '$.Addresses',
   JSON_QUERY(
      (
      SELECT *
      FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.Addresses') WITH (
         Address nvarchar(1000) '$.Address',
         City nvarchar(1000) '$.City',
         State nvarchar(1000) '$.State'
      )
      WHERE Address <> N'Test 1'
      FOR JSON PATH
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: A query of the form `SELECT @var = <expression involving @var> FROM <table>` is non-deterministic and not guaranteed to be evaluated in the order you expect it to be. It's one of those things that works 99 times out of 100, and then breaks in the next update of the optimizer. In 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` to easily build a JSON array, so there's no real need for that trick. For 2016 things get a lot more annoying.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, you are right. I should post this as a note at the end of the answer, probably the order of the items in the "Addresses" array is important. Thanks.

Comment: This won't populate any nested properties in the target object. I.e if Addresses had a nested object for the location with lang/long coordinates the object would not appear in the new JSON data

Answer (score 0):

We can Open Json then delete the value and replace new json value as follows:

```
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @JSONData = N'{  
        "FirstName":"Jignesh",  
        "LastName":"Trivedi",  
        "Code":"CCEEDD",  
        "Addresses":[  
            { "Address":"Test 0", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
            { "Address":"Test 1", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"}  
        ]  
    }'
            

    SELECT @JSONData=(SELECT oj.FirstName 'FirstName',oj.LastName 'LastName',oj.Code,JSON_VALUE(oj2.Value,'$.Address') AS 'Addresses.Address',JSON_VALUE(oj2.Value,'$.City')  'Addresses.City',
    JSON_VALUE(oj2.Value,'$.State') AS 'Addresses.State' FROM 
    OPENJSON(@JSONData)
    WITH 
    (FirstName NVARCHAR(max),LastName NVARCHAR(max),Code NVARCHAR(max),Addresses NVARCHAR(max) AS JSON)oj
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(oj.Addresses) oj2
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(oj2.Value,'$.Address')<>'Test 1'
    FOR JSON PATH)
        PRINT @JSONData
```